# Python Pandas - Conditional Join

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join

I would like to create a DataFrame from a DataFrame I already have in Python.

The DataFrame I have looks like below:

```
Nome    Dept
Maria   A1
Joao    A2
Anna    A1
Jorge   A3
```

The DataFrame I want to create is like the below:

```
Dept    Funcionario 1      Funcionario 2
A1          Maria              Anna
A2          Joao
```

I tried the below code:

```py
df_func.merge(df_dept, how='inner', on='Dept')
```

But I got the error: `TypeError: merge() got multiple values for argument 'how'`

Would anyone know how I can do this?

Thank you in Advance! :)

Comment: Is df_func your first table? If not it should be. first_table.merge(second_table, how=“Inner” on=“dept”) - you have stated what your original table is called so this is just an assumption.

Comment: I changed and it joined the two tables, but I would like to make the dept table the main one and the other fill the dept table like employee 1 and employee 2 based on the department.

Comment: what does `pd.merge(df_dept,df_func,on='Dept',how='inner')` yield?

Comment: What is a "table" in Python? I am not familiar with this datatype. Do you mean Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, it's a Dataframe, sorry, I'm gonna fix it.

Comment: Are you able to post both your tables? To make your dept table your main one, put that into a data frame first, then join that with your secondary table.

Comment: I am trying to not have the Dept repeated on the new DataFrame.
I want to have the employees (Funcionario) listed by the department.
Like: Department   Employee 1   Employee 2
               1                    Anna             Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you try that and it works, you will not get the right answer. in fact the key is gonna be duplicated 4 times.

```
{'Name': ['maria', 'joao', 'anna', 'jorge'], 'dept': [1, 2, 1, 3]}
{'Name': ['maria', 'joao', 'anna', 'jorge'], 'dept': [1, 2, 1, 3]}
d = _
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.merge(df, how='inner', on='dept')

Out[8]: 
  Name_x  dept Name_y
0  maria     1  maria
1  maria     1   anna
2   anna     1  maria
3   anna     1   anna
4   joao     2   joao
5  jorge     3  jorge
```

Best way around is to `groupby` :

```
dd = df.groupby('dept').agg(list)
Out[10]: 
               Name
dept               
1     [maria, anna]
2            [joao]
3           [jorge]
```

Then you apply `pd.Series`

```
dd['Name'].apply(pd.Series)

Out[21]: 
          0     1
dept             
1     maria  anna
2      joao   NaN
3     jorge   NaN
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you so much!
You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have merged two data frames recently.

```py
rpt_data = connect_to_presto() # returned data from a db
df_rpt = pd.DataFrame(rpt_data, columns=["domain", "revenue"])

""" adding sellers.json seller {} into a panads df """
sj_data = data # returned response from requests module
df_sj = pd.json_normalize(sj_data, record_path="sellers", errors="ignore")

""" merging both dataframes """
df_merged = df_rpt.merge(df_sj, how="inner", on="domain", indicator=True)
```

Notice how I have stored the data into a variable each time, then created a DataFrame out of that? Then merged them like so

```py
df_merged = df_rpt.merge(df_sj, how="inner", on="domain", indicator=True)
```

This may not be the best approach but it works.